# Repartioning Large Files in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am very new to Spark and got a file of 1 TB to process.

My system specification is :

Each node: 64 GB RAM

Number Of nodes:2

Cores per node: 5

As I  know I have to repartition the data for better parallelism  as  spark will try to create default partition only by (totalNumber of cores * 2 or 3 or 4).
But in my case since Data file is very huge, I have to repartition this data to a number such that this data can be processed in a efficient manner.

How to choose the number of Partitions to be passed in repartition??How should I calculate  it?What approach I should take to solve this..

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`partitions` and `parallelism` are two different things per my understanding. However  both go hand in hand when it comes to parallel executions of tasks in Spark.
Parallelism is `number of executors * number of cores` , which in your case is `2 * 5 = 10`. So at any given moment you could have 10 tasks running at most.
If your data is divided into 10 partitions then all of it would be processing at once. However if you have 20 partitions then Spark would start processing 10 partitions and based on when each task finish , spark will schedule next partitions to process. This will happen until it finish processing all the partitions.

By default one partition is one block of data. I am guessing your 1 TB of Data is stored on HDFS. If underlying block size is 256MB then you would have 1TB/256MB number of blocks which in turn are partitions.

Please note that once the data is read you can always repartition it based on your requirement.

> How to choose the number of Partitions to be passed in
> repartition??How should I calculate it?What approach I should take to
> solve this..

You need to see how your spark application holds up with the size of partition and then determine if you can decrease or increase that number. One thing is the executor memory consideration as well. If your partition is too big then you can run into OutOfMemory errors as well. These are just the guidelines and not the extensive list.

This https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/ multipart series has more detailed discussion on partitions and executors.